# Плавный скролл с scrollSpeed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нашел удобный вариант создания плавного скролла с Jquery. Все бы отлично но есть 1 проблема/баг. После обновления странички где-то в центре браузер автоматически перемещает меня туда, но разработчик скрипта видимо это не предвидел и если я крутну колесико мышки перемещаюсь в самое начало страницы.

Я уже сделал попытки исправить это, я нашел что проблема по видимости в переменной `root` которая всегда изначально 0. Я пробовал задать ей высоту wheelDeltaY или wheelDelta, deltaY, но не работает почему-то.

Вы не могли бы взглянуть на код скрипта и корректировать его? Благодарю за внимание.

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/w1gzqmp1/) если так будет удобнее, а ниже код по правилам.

```js
$(function() {
        $.scrollSpeed(100, 450);
    });
 
 // Plugin: jQuery.scrollSpeed
// Source: github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed
// Author: Nathan Rutzky
// Update: 1.0.2

(function($) {
    
    jQuery.scrollSpeed = function(step, speed, easing) {
        
        var $document = $(document),
            $window = $(window),
            $body = $('html, body'),
            option = easing || 'default',
            root = 0,
            scroll = false,
            scrollY,
            scrollX,
            view;
            
        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)
        
            return false;
            
        $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            
            var deltaY = e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY,
                detail = e.originalEvent.detail;
                scrollY = $document.height() > $window.height();
                scrollX = $document.width() > $window.width();
                scroll = true;
            
            if (scrollY) {
                
                view = $window.height();
                    
                if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            
                    root = (root + view) >= $document.height() ? root : root += step;
                
                if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            
                    root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
                
                $body.stop().animate({
            
                    scrollTop: root
                
                }, speed, option, function() {
            
                    scroll = false;
                
                });
            }
            
            if (scrollX) {
                
                view = $window.width();
                    
                if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            
                    root = (root + view) >= $document.width() ? root : root += step;
                
                if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            
                    root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
                
                $body.stop().animate({
            
                    scrollLeft: root
                
                }, speed, option, function() {
            
                    scroll = false;
                
                });
            }
            
            return false;
            
        }).on('scroll', function() {
            
            if (scrollY && !scroll) root = $window.scrollTop();
            if (scrollX && !scroll) root = $window.scrollLeft();
            
        }).on('resize', function() {
            
            if (scrollY && !scroll) view = $window.height();
            if (scrollX && !scroll) view = $window.width();
            
        });       
    };
    
    jQuery.easing.default = function (x,t,b,c,d) {
    
        return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    };
    
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1><b>jQuery.scrollSpeed</b> is a lightweight jQuery extension for
    custom scrolling speed in modern web browsers. Supports vertical or
    horizontal scrolling direction, including user-defined easing.
    Singapore conversation business class, vibrant sharp Swiss Ettinger bespoke
    Lufthansa discerning Toto handsome. Bulletin sleepy conversation hand-crafted
    international. Washlet alluring elegant, Sunspel charming vibrant Swiss the
    best Helsinki liveable lovely Singapore flat white intricate. Boulevard
    Tsutaya discerning uniforms Zürich Sunspel Ettinger perfect first-class St
    Moritz bespoke. Cutting-edge bulletin soft power concierge vibrant the
    best. Ginza charming impeccable, izakaya hand-crafted global Lufthansa soft
    power. Alluring Fast Lane hub, pintxos St Moritz intricate Nordic wardrobe
    first-class boutique Boeing 787. Business class carefully curated global,
    izakaya airport Helsinki Ettinger Melbourne. International cosy liveable
    Sunspel ryokan Washlet ANA signature joy artisanal. Hand-crafted pintxos
    bespoke soft power. Charming lovely pintxos Melbourne Toto bureaux
    Singapore first-class. Impeccable Porter exquisite quality of life
    liveable. Pintxos boulevard ryokan sophisticated handsome Sunspel Baggu
    elegant wardrobe signature Zürich hub Ginza eclectic Beams. Airbus A380
    Shinkansen bespoke, Helsinki Baggu ANA bulletin cutting-edge Swiss Gaggenau
    elegant hand-crafted Singapore. Marylebone St Moritz emerging espresso
    Swiss. Conversation boulevard destination Ettinger, Gaggenau St Moritz
    artisanal sleepy pintxos Beams Shinkansen business class Nordic emerging.
    St Moritz artisanal eclectic the best, joy Baggu Washlet wardrobe Comme des
    Garçons vibrant Beams Swiss. K-pop pintxos liveable exclusive the best
    global smart flat white remarkable Zürich Scandinavian tote bag Baggu
    hand-crafted. Elegant pintxos Baggu Beams Swiss. Elegant Asia-Pacific
    pintxos izakaya bespoke, vibrant flat white exquisite. Intricate
    Scandinavian finest Baggu Gaggenau smart elegant Helsinki Airbus A380
    Swiss. Bureaux smart Nordic, Lufthansa Ginza Singapore extraordinary
    cutting-edge ryokan lovely Comme des Garçons perfect liveable joy Muji.
    Global craftsmanship intricate, flat white Helsinki Winkreative Beams
    izakaya airport ryokan artisanal Ettinger handsome Toto.</h1>

 </body></html>
```

Comment: Правда все-равно придется скопировать код себе что бы проверить это ибо браузер не запоминает положения фреймов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте сделать такую замену

root = $document.scrollTop(),

Comment: Большое спасибо!